# Ansible doesn't return job ID for async task

Tags: ansible

According to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-ad-hoc-tasks) when I run an async ad hoc command I should get a job ID back so I can check the status later.  That's not happening:

```
$ ansible all -a "sleep 60" -P 0 -B 86400
node1 | SUCCESS | rc=-1 >>


node2 | SUCCESS | rc=-1 >>


node0 | SUCCESS | rc=-1 >>


node3 | SUCCESS | rc=-1 >>


$
```

The `sleep` command is running on all nodes, so the task does run correctly:

```
$ ssh node2 ps aux | grep sleep
$ ansible node2 --user ${USER} --background 3600 --poll 0 --args "/bin/sleep 10s"
node2 | SUCCESS | rc=-1 >>


$ ssh node2 ps aux | grep sleep
user  7232  0.0  0.0   7468   744 ?        S    13:54   0:00 /bin/sleep 10s
$
```

But I have no way of checking the status with the `async_status` job since I don't know the job ID.  Is there a way to list currently running async jobs?  Or some other way to get the job ID?

Ubuntu 18.04.1, ansible 2.5.1, python 2.7.17.

Comment: The job_id is only meaningful within the context of a playbook, since ad-hoc mode (running the `ansible` script) does not spawn background processes that outlive the `ansible` command itself, and thus there is no job with an ID that one could check on later

Comment: If you use the `-B` option then the process does outlive the `ansible` command.  The documentation I linked to has a section "Asynchronous ad hoc tasks" that says to use the job ID to check on job status.

Comment: After your update I wonder, are you connecting via `ssh` into the target host and than execute the command `ansible` there connecting to itself? What would be the output of `ansible node2 --user ${USER} --module-name shell --args "ps aux | grep sleep"`?

Comment: As already mentioned, can you perform some tests with different but simple ad-hoc but commands which will deliver known (good) results? I.e. like `ansible test --user ${USER} --ask-pass --module-name shell --args "echo test; echo rc=$?"`. The output should than be something like `test1.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
test
rc=0
`.

Comment: You may also try `ansible test --user ${USER} --ask-pass --module-name shell --args "echo 'test '; exit -1;"`

Comment: Yup, that works fine: `$ ansible node2 --user ${USER}  --module-name shell --args  echo test; echo rc=$?"` outputs `node2 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >> test rc=0` (newlines removed).

Comment: Not sure if this was your intention but `exit -1` returns an error, which ansible does correctly recognize: `ansible node2 --user ${USER}  --module-name shell --args "echo 'test '; exit -1;"` outputs `node2 | FAILED | rc=2 >>
test /bin/sh: 1: exit: Illegal number: -1non-zero return code`

Comment: Right, that was the intension. That test should return an error `FAILED | rc=255 >>
test non-zero return code` or similar. Your shell seems not to recognize the `-1`, thats why the it seems the `exit` command complained about the `Illegal number: -1`. You may also try with just `1`.

Comment: I don't know which shell Ubuntu 18.04 has, if I execute `ansible test --user ${USER} --ask-pass --module-name shell --args "/bin/sh --version"` I get `test1.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release ...`. I assume yours will be different.

Comment: Right my shell returned an error, but ansible handled it correctly - the return code from the shell was 2 (if you run `/bin/sh -c "exit -1"; echo rc=$?`, rc=2).  I'm not sure how this is related to my issue, especially since the command I ran originally did not return an error.

Comment: Regarding "_how this is related to my issue_" I am still wondering why your initial command reports `SUCCESS | rc=-1` with an empty result whereby it should be `CHANGED | rc=0` with output. Such I haven't seen til now and no further ideas yet.